# Socket connection is not closed, then navigate back to Launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have an Fiori Elements application, which consumes an Socket connection over the object:

```
sap/ui/core/ws/WebSocket
```

If an message is send to the Frontend, the App shows an PopUp.

Problem:

1. User uses APP
2. User navigates to Launchpad
3. Socket connection is not closed
4. Message is send by Socket
5. PopUp is shown in Launchpad
   [image: Launchpad with PopUp]

How can I achieve that no PopUp is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple, implement onExit method of Controller would do the trick

```
onExit() {
  this.socket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if a WebSocket object is created in the Component.js, be sure that the WebSocket is initialized in the Component `init()` function and call the WebSocket `close()` method in the Component `exit()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, onExit works in Controller